# How to use ListTile inside horizontal ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use ListTiles as items of the horizontal ListView.

```
final brandsWidget = SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: [
      ListTile(
        leading: Image.asset('img_1.png'),
        title: Text('Product 1'),
        subtitle: Text('\$5'),
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: Image.asset('img_1.png),
        title: Text('Product 2'),
        subtitle: Text('\$3'),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

I got the following error:

```
Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
Exception caught by rendering library.
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
The relevant error-causing widget was ListTile
```

Comment: wrap `ListTile` with `SizedBox` for example

Comment: If your brandsWidget isn't inside a Row, then you need to wrap your ListTiles in a container to set a defined width.  By definition, ListTiles do not have set width and will extend endlessly with a constraint.

Comment: ListTile has infinite width. Wrap it with other Widget like container and give specific width.

Comment: It works after wrapped in SizedBox with width specified. Thanks pskink and Kedar.

Comment: @ScottGodfrey it's inside a vertical ListView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can uses `ListTile` widget by wrapping it with `Container` or `SizedBox widget.`

**Error Explanation:**

You are getting this error because `ListTiles` have `infinite width`. If you don't give them a proper one they will surely generate such errors.